# Where does an accumulator variable in Spark live?

Tags: apache-spark

My assumption is that an accumulator is maintained within the Spark Context in the driver program. Unlike broadcast variables, an accumulator's value is not sent to Worker Nodes in the cluster. Is this correct ? If so, what are the mechanics of how it gets updated in the Spark Context ?  How are updates to it from the various Executors on the worker nodes implemented ? Is it a Singleton object ?

Answer (score 1):

To quote from the [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators-a-nameaccumlinka)

> Tasks running on the cluster can then add to it using the add method or the += operator (in Scala and Python). However, they cannot read its value. Only the driver program can read the accumulator’s value, using its value method.

Looking at the implementation, it seems that the accumulator keeps its value at the driver side (where it can be read).

As for the executors. I see that the accumulator is registered to the `TaskContext` upon deserialization. So it seems that the executors keep their own internal accumulator, which is later merged with the real accumulator of the driver.

The accumulator is not a singleton object, since multiple accumulators can be created. However the executors have a means to communicate with the original accumulator of the driver application.

Comment: But if the executors keep their own internal accumulator, how does an update by an executor occur ? So executor 1 say adds 2, executor 2 adds 1 etc, are these then all added up by the driver program in its "golden" accumulator ?

Comment: Yes. From what I have seen in the code, the accumulator has a merge function which is used to combine the results of executors to compute the final result in the driver.